# How to determine the flutter & dart sdk version of old flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, sdk, mobile-development

I need to know the flutter and dart sdk versions used on an old project,
This my pubspec.lock part for flutter

```
flutter:
  dependency: "direct main"
  description: flutter
  source: sdk
  version: "0.0.0"
```

and this is pubspec.lock part for sdks

```
sdks:
  dart: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.22.2"
```

Comment: You note in a comment that you "tried Dart sdk in this range and also this version of flutter sdk with no luck" - what happened when you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided content, It appears that the project is utilising the `Flutter` `SDK version >=1.22.2` and `Dart` `SDK versions >=2.14.0 and <3.0.0`, respectively, based on the `pubspec.lock` file you provided.

Comment: No it's not, I tried Dart sdk in this range and also this version of flutter sdk with no luck

Comment: What do you want to do with the version, can you let me know, so that I can assist you better, but the sdk is based on your question's content.

Comment: I want to run the app, and my current sdk version is not compatible